# Going back to the working dir after hitting u a couple of times in Vim, NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I thought I was working in a vim file and wanted to undo by hitting `u`. But sometimes I do it in NERDTree and it moves tree root up a dir by mistake.

Now I have to dig into directories to go back my working directory. Is there any simpler way to display my working directory in NERDTree?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Bookmarks are displayed on top of the tree, you can create a Bookmark of you working dir. Move to the working dir and type `:Bookmark` in command mode. The name of the dir appears in curly braces next to the dir name. (Be aware that no spaces are in dir name. Is that the case, you have to name the Bookmark by you own with `Bookmark <name>`).

To display Bookmarks, type `B` in NERDTree buffer.

Have also a look into the help: `:help nerdtree`